# SELECT count(*) with OR operator

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use `SELECT COUNT(*)` in a prepared statement.

Below is my PHP:

```
if(!($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS failed FROM LoginAttempts WHERE (email = ? OR IP = ?) AND LastLogin BETWEEN now() and subdate(now(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)"))){
}

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $ip);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($failed);

$stmt->close();
```

What I'm trying to achieve from this, is when a user tries to login to their account (and provides incorrect login information) their IP, and the entered email address is logged in a table.

When an attempt is tried to login, using their email **or** IP, I count how many records match **either** their IP or email address.

The issue I'm having, is when accessing `$failed` the result is `NULL` even though there are records in the database within the last 5 minutes.

Where exactly am I going wrong? There are no errors in my apache error log, or with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Thanks for your time

**Edit:** I needed to use $stmt->fetch(); - not sure how I missed that. Thanks to Saty for your comment!

Comment: You need to close if condition before `$stmt->close();`

Comment: Does that query work when you run it in the database?  I typically start in the db and once I've got a reliable query then I convert it to a prepared statement syntax.  That lets me separate errors in the statement from errors getting connectivity to the db.

Comment: Look at this `if(!($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS failed FROM LoginAttempts WHERE (email = ? OR IP = ?) AND LastLogin BETWEEN now() and subdate(now(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)"))){
}` - Move the closing brace further down.

Comment: and check for errors against your query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  - you're not doing that. `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$link->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: I think you need to fetch data form query result then access `$failed` as 
   `while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s", $failed);
    }`

Comment: @Saty Appologies for not replying, I was trying the suggestions posted. Thanks for your suggestion, solved my issue. If you post as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few mistake in your code

1) Not looking for errors

2) Close if condition at the end

3) Forget to fetch data form query result

You code would be

```
if (!($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS failed FROM LoginAttempts WHERE (email = ? OR IP = ?) AND LastLogin BETWEEN now() and subdate(now(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)"))) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $ip);
    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();
    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($failed);
    /* fetch value */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s", $failed);
    }
    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with between clause

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS failed FROM LoginAttempts 
WHERE (email = ? OR IP = ?) AND LastLogin
 BETWEEN  subdate(now(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) and now()
```

try this and let me know

Comment: Still getting `NULL` as a result, even though I used the code you suggested

Comment: try to execute it directly against the database.  that between clause incorrect and definitely you have to correct it .

Comment: please try it directly on db and let me know

Comment: I tried it directly against my DB, got no issues. Turned out it was with my PHP, I needed to use $stmt->fetch(); - completely went over my head. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @PublicDisplayName : that means you have to add some fix form php level but i have know clue about it

Answer (score 1):

A few errors in here, but mainly you forgot to fetch the result after binding it to a variable. `bind_param` basically indicates the variable to  place the values from the result set it does not actually do the retrieval of a row from the result set, you need some sort of `->fetch()` to do that

Its a good idea to test all the status's of almost all `mysqli_` api calls and output the error somewhere, they are normally very useful and fairly precise. A great aid in debugging a complex query

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS failed 
                        FROM LoginAttempts 
                        WHERE (email = ? OR IP = ?) 
                          AND LastLogin BETWEEN now() and subdate(now(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)");

if ( $stmt === FALSE ) {
    echo $link->error;
    exit;
}

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $ip);

$result = $stmt->execute();
if ( $result === false ) {
    echo $link->error;
    exit;
}

$stmt->bind_result($failed);
$stmt->fetch();   // this actually get the value out of the result set into $failed   

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I'm currently just developing at the moment, however I plan to use Sentry or Bugsnag to log exceptions so I can see what happens globally without having to rummage through apache error logs. Thanks for your time, completely missed using `fetch();`